# Returning new object containing selected key value pairs in typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ngfor

I've got massive object of type person, and I want to display only a few (might grow) values if they exist. One row div of key-value, if they're specified in some array eg. hasProperty

My idea is to get a Person object, map it with array like
`hasProperty:string[]=['dateOfBirth','address']`
to a new object
so then on the front-end i can do something like

```
<div for=newObjectValue in newObject>
 <span>key somehow?</span>
 <span>{{newObjectValue.value`}}</span>
</div>
```

Is this possible to be done better? I know the idea above is terrible, but that's the best i've come up with so far

Comment: You could also use `ngIf` and check if the key is in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple do like this

`app.component.ts`

```
person = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'John'
  age: 20,
  nationality: Canadian,
  ......
};
personObjectKeys = Object.keys(person);
```

And inside your template, you can do it in a loop like this
`app.component.html`

```
<div class="record-row" *ngFor="let personKey of personObjectKeys">
   <ng-container *ngIf="person[personKey]">
     <span>{{personKey}}</span>
     <span>{{person[personKey]}}</span>
   </ng-container>
</div>
```